# Мне необходимо обнулить (либо поставить единичку) на одну из ножек микроконтроллера

Tags: c++, stm32

Цель задания: Управлять лампочкой путем (замкнута/разомкнута) контакта преемника, который управляется микроконтроллером. 
Задачей зажжением светодиода схожа, но единственное отличие в том что все светодиоды горят по умолчанию, без дополнительного кода. Моя задача сводится тому, чтоб эти светодиоды включать/выключить при определенной команде. Например: нажатии кнопки. Какой преемник какой ножке микроконтроллера относится мной определен.

Прошу расписать подробно.

Comment: Нужно больше данных. Пример кода. На чём пишете... Генерируемый ли чем то проект или пример от куда-то...

Answer (score 0):

Если используется FreeRTOS - 
GPIOx инициализируйте на необходимой ножке и выставляйте

Comment: Вы б удалили первое предложение из ответа, а то иногда вопросительные предложения вводят в заблуждение проверяющих: кажется, что это не ответ, а комментарий к вопросу в котором уточняются детали.